# How to return my expression in sympy with the non-symbolic names of the variables?

Tags: python, printing, sympy

I am using sympy in Python, where I have many variables. I would like to assign a name to a variable, let's say `variable1=sympy.symbols(r'\alpha)`, then manipulate an expression that includes `variable1` and then print the expression in python code with `variable1` instead of its symbol. For example:

```
import sympy
variable1, variable2, x = sympy.symbols(r'\alpha \beta x') #variables
y=sympy.Function(r'y')(x) #another variable in the form of a function
z = sympy.Derivative(y, x, 1) #derivative of y
expr1=x+y - variable1 # example expression 1
expr2=x-y - variable2 # example expression 2
solutions = sympy.solve([expr1,expr2], x, y, dict=True) #solve for x and y
print(solutions[0][x]) #prints solution for x
```

This prints `\alpha/2 + \beta/2` but how do I get it to print `variable1/2+variable2/2`?'

Also if the expression has a derivative it gets printed as `Derivative(y, x)` and not `z`.

The `print` outputs seem to be fitted to be used in latex, but is there a more natural print function to return expression for a python code?

I am attempting to extract an equation that I can use in another python code that uses numpy.

Comment: Why don't you just set your variable with the name you like, e.g., `variable1 = "variable1"`? You could also modify the string, something like `print(str(solutions[0][x]).replace(r"\alpha", "variable1").replace(r"\beta", "variable2"))`.

Comment: @OnDraganov its a problem between visualization and what I need. If I call the variable `var1` then when I visualize it it looks like *var1* and in latex that looks like `v*a*r*1`

Comment: `symbols` makes sympy objects, which have the specified string representation. The `variable1=...` just assigns that object to a python variable.  That variable lets you reference that symbol objecct in code,  but the string 'variable1' is not used for display, inpython or sympy.  A python variable is not the same thing as the stting.

Comment: Sounds like you need to reread this `symbols` getcha page, https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorials/intro-tutorial/gotchas.html#symbols.  You seem to have a fuzzy grasp of python variables are.

Comment: How about `.replace(r"\alpha", r"\textrm{variable1}")`? As others point out, programatically, it really does not make much sense to print the name of a variable in your code from within the code. So you should think about your problem in the following way: `sympy` prints the solution with some "internal" variable names, how do I change those "internal" names into "actual" names? And then it is just manipulating strings.

Answer (score 1):

Simply mapping the variable names to the symbol names in sympy should do the trick.

```
import sympy

variable1, variable2, x, y = sympy.symbols(r'\alpha \beta x y') #variables
symbol_map = {
    r'\alpha': "variable1",
    r'\beta': "variable2",
    'x': "x",
    'y': "y",
}
expr1=x+y - variable1 # example expression 1
expr2=x-y - variable2 # example expression 2
solutions = sympy.solve([expr1,expr2], x, y, dict=True) #solve for x and y

out = str(solutions[0][x])
for key, value in symbol_map.items():
    out = out.replace(key, value)

print(out)
```

Comment: so you confirm that there is no natural way to do so? there is no internal map between variable and assigned symbol?

Comment: I am not sure what it is that you are after. I think that you should consider reformulating the question, since it is a bit misleading and will probably not yield the answer that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

`alpha` and `beta` are values and `variable1` and `variable2` are variables. I don't know of a way in Python to find out which variables are associated with a given value, e.g. in the following, `3` is the value and `x` and `y` both are assigned that value. How would you go backwards from 3 to `x` and `y`?

```py
x = 3
y = 3
```

What you can do, however, is to keep track of both variables and values like

```py
vari = symbols('variable1:3')
valu = symbols(r'\alpha \beta')
orig = dict(zip(valu, vari))

import sympy
variable1, variable2, x = sympy.symbols(r'\alpha \beta x') #variables
y=sympy.Function(r'y')(x) #another variable in the form of a function
z = sympy.Derivative(y, x, 1) #derivative of y
expr1=x+y - variable1 # example expression 1
expr2=x-y - variable2 # example expression 2
solutions = sympy.solve([expr1,expr2], x, y, dict=True) #solve for x and y
>>> print(solutions[0][x].subs(orig))
variable1/2 + variable2/2
```